# custom route in rails 4 not working

Tags: url, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

I've created custom routes to route to News model

```
    resources :news, only: [:index] do
     collection do
      get 'page/:page', action: :index
     end
    end

    get "news/:id(/p/:p)", to: 'news#show', as: 'news'
```

generate url like this

```
http://localhost:3000/news/4/page/2  index.html.erb  is right
```

and show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'news', news_path(@news, '2')%>

I hope generate url http://localhost:3000/news/4/p/2  

but generate http://localhost:3000/news/4?p=2
```

Comment: "news/:id(/p/:p)" - what are the brackets for? Take them out.

Comment: in the url (/p/:p) dispensable, url http://localhost:3000/news/4  or http://localhost:3000/news/4/p/1 or http://localhost:3000/news/4/p/all

Comment: Can you do a "rake routes" and post?

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got a route conflict, change this:

```
get "news/:id(/p/:p)", to: 'news#show', as: 'news'
```

to this:

```
get "news/:id(/p/:p)", to: 'news#show', as: 'news_page'
```

and the use this link:

```
<%= link_to 'News', news_page_path(@news, '2')%>
```